# Web Deploy to subfolder, except bin

Tags: .net, iis, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

I have a web application project that I would like to publish to my website using Web Deploy from Visual Studio. However, I want the files in the project (that are set to be published) to be deployed under a subfolder structure, `foo`, ***except*** for the `bin` and `App_Data` directories, which should still be deployed under root. Is there a clean way of doing this by altering the `.pubxml` config file?

Some concerns I've run into:

- I assume I cannot set the `<DeployIisAppPath>` element to point to the subfolder, since it won't allow me to publish the `bin` and `App_Data` folders at the root.
- I want to limit the files that get picked up to be the ones that would normally be published by Web Deploy. I don't want to deploy my `.cs` files.
- I don't know the full set of files extensions in advance, so I cannot define an exhaustive filter based on them (e.g. `*.html|*.js|...`). I want to restrict any filter definitions to the `bin` and `App_Data` folders.
- I want to preserve the folder structure of the files. For example, `bar\Default.html` should go to `foo\bar\Default.html`.
- I would like the results of this process to be available within the Web Deploy Preview window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out; I needed to define a `Target` with a [`Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595163.aspx) task that executes after `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy`. This goes after the `<PropertyGroup>` in the `.pubxml` file:

```
<Target Name="MoveFilesToDesignatedDirectory" 
        AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy">
  <Message Text="Moving files to designated directory" importance="high" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <_CustomMoveFiles Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\**"
                      Exclude="$(_PackageTempDir)\bin\**;
                               $(_PackageTempDir)\App_Data\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Move SourceFiles="%(_CustomMoveFiles.Identity)"
        DestinationFolder="$(_PackageTempDir)\foo\%(RecursiveDir)" />
</Target>
```

References:

- Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi's [VS Web Publish: How to include files outside of the project to be published](http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,b352f04a-2449-4cbb-8125-7acdef9552e1.aspx)
- Keith Beller's [VS 2012 Publishing Profiles and Copy Files Using MSBuilld Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14324045/1149773)